# JavaFX 18.0.1 + Windows 11 + JDK 18.0.1.1: Canvas - cannot trigger the touch screen events

Tags: java, javafx, touch

My setup:

- JavaFX SDK 18.0.1
- Windows 11
- JDK 18.0.1.1
- A screen with the touch support

When I try a simple program, none of the touch events are triggered upon touch gestures. My test app follows.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.input.TouchEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFXSandbox extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(600, 600);
        root.getChildren().add(canvas);

        stage.addEventFilter(TouchEvent.ANY, e -> System.out.println("touch event: " + e));

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Is there any way of circumventing the issue, or am I misusing the JavaFX API?

Comment: no touch device here - but found a qa that might answer the why (not how to fix ;) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69203599/javafx-no-touchevents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing a bit with JavaFX, I found out that touch events are converted to mouse events such, that it's possible to simulate touch events in mouse listeners.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a universal thing. Whether touch events are converted to mouse events or not is likely operating system/device dependent (i.e., it depends on what kind of events are passed to the JavaFX application). Assuming JavaFX properly handles touch events, of course.

Comment: On systems where touch events are converted to mouse events, some information will be lost in the conversion. For example a [touch event](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/TouchEvent.html) can have multiple [touch points](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/TouchPoint.html) each with different [states](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/18/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/TouchPoint.State.html). Not all of that info can be represented by a mouse event.